# Text box adding multiple lines of text without replacing the first line of text

Tags: c#

I started making a story WPF application in c#, i'm almost finished except for the automatic text. What i want my app to do is start in the title window, press a button and have it go to the next window and the text will automatically start showing to the user (as though they are reading the story) once the story for that window is done, i want to go to the next window for them to read that story. I have all the buttons working, but When i enter the code for the text it replaces the first line with the last line. Here's my code for the text. I'm using a text box for it.

```
enjoychat.Text = "Hallo, ";
timerWait.Wait(1500);
enjoychat.Text = "How are you, ";
timerWait.Wait(1500);
enjoychat.Text = "Goodbye, ";
```

i want the results to be:

hallo   (wait 1.5 seconds)
how are you (wait 1.5 seconds)
Goodbye

Comment: try using enjoychat.Text +=

Comment: Hi there. Try: enjoychat.Text = enjoychat + "\rHow are you, ";

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `+=` operator to append text like so:

```
enjoychat.Text = "Hallo, ";
timerWait.Wait(1500);
enjoychat.Text += "How are you, ";
timerWait.Wait(1500);
enjoychat.Text += "Goodbye, ";
```

If you want to add a newline, use `Enviromnent.NewLine` like so:

```
enjoychat.Text += Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `enjoychat.Text +=` for concatenating the string! Or you can add data to a variable using `+=` and finally assign to `enjoychat.Text`.